# Add Bleed to jQuery visible plugin

Tags: jquery, visible

I'm using the jQuery visible plugin: [link here](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery).

It's working great except I'm trying to make the "visible" reading to detect earlier. Currently, it seems like its not being read as "visible" until the entire element is shown inside the window. I don't see any bleed parameters to set for the plugin.

Is there a way I can set a manual bleed to trigger the visible detection sooner?

```
$('.featured_work .item').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<span></span>');
    // Is this element visible onscreen?
    var visible = $(this).visible();
    if (visible == true) {
         $(this).find('.black_box').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not relying on JQuery, this feature is easily computed without it.

```
var isVisible = function(element) {
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (box.bottom > 0 && box.bottom < window.innerHeight) {
        return true;
    } else if (box.top > 0 && box.top < window.innerHeight) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```